# Update and log only changed rows with SQL in SQLite

Tags: sql, r, sqlite, triggers

I am writing an application/script in R that updates a SQLite database.

My apologies - I am not experienced with this.

My table consists of 4 fields `Id`,`Name`,`LVL`,`Notes`:

```
CREATE TABLE members (
Id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
Name TEXT NOT NULL,
LVL INTEGER NOT NULL,
Notes TEXT
);

INSERT INTO members (Name,LVL,Notes)
VALUES  ('Jean',12,'First stage'),
        ('Jacques',1,'Second stage'),
        ('Amelie',1,'Second stage'),
        ('Louis',13,'Some other note altogether')
;
```

I want to check it against another table `tmp`

```
CREATE TABLE tmp (
Name TEXT NOT NULL,
LVL INTEGER NOT NULL,
Notes TEXT
);

INSERT INTO tmp (Name,LVL,Notes)
VALUES  ('Jean',13,'First stage'),
        ('Jacques',1,'Second stage'),
        ('Amelie',1,'Third stage'),
        ('Louis',14,'Fourth stage')
;
```

and if there are changes in LVL and/or Notes fields (as LVL for Jean and Louis and Notes for Amelie and Louis) I want to update the `members` table with new values after I record the previous values (as whole rows) with a timestamp in `member_changes` table.

What would be the minimal set of queries to achieve this?

And what is the better design of the `member_changes` table? Would it be the same as `members` but with added `rowID` as primary key and `timestamp` fields? And naturally memberID would allow duplicates.

Many thanks,

Rob

## SYNOPSIS of expanded answer

Thanks to @forpas kind answer I put this small system together with 2 additional triggers. New information comes in via `tmp` table. Member names are presumed to be unique; possibly primary key on `members.Id` was not needed. Nevertheless:

```sql
-- CREATE members table for current guild members
-- Id is prim key and Name has unique index
CREATE TABLE members (
  Id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  Name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  LVL INTEGER NOT NULL,
  Notes TEXT
);
-- SAMPLE DATA
INSERT INTO members (Name,LVL,Notes) VALUES  
        ('Jean',12,'First stage'),
        ('Jacques',1,'Second stage'),
        ('Amelie',1,'Second stage'),
        ('Louis',13,'Some other note altogether');
-- LOG table to see membership changes over time
CREATE TABLE members_changes (
  timestamp TEXT DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  Id INTEGER REFERENCES members(Id),
  Name TEXT NOT NULL,
  LVL INTEGER NOT NULL,
  Notes TEXT
);
-- TABLE through which the updates will come in via rvest
-- presumed cannot contain duplicate names
CREATE TABLE tmp (
  Name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  LVL INTEGER NOT NULL,
  Notes TEXT
);
-- TRIGGERS (3)
-- (1) UPDATES MEMBERS if insertion in tmp shows changes
-- also LOGS this change in members_changes
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS tr_insert_tmp AFTER INSERT ON tmp
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO members_changes(Id,Name,LVL,Notes)
  SELECT Id,Name,LVL,Notes
  FROM members
  WHERE Name = NEW.NAME AND (LVL IS NOT NEW.LVL OR Notes IS NOT NEW.Notes);
  
  UPDATE members 
  SET LVL = NEW.LVL, Notes = NEW.Notes
  WHERE Name = NEW.Name AND (LVL IS NOT NEW.LVL OR Notes IS NOT NEW.Notes);
END;
-- (2) LOGS DELETIONS from members
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS tr_delete_members BEFORE DELETE ON members
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO members_changes(Id,Name,LVL,Notes)
    SELECT Id,Name,LVL,Notes || " :Deleted"
    FROM members
    WHERE Name = OLD.Name;
END;
-- (3) LOGS INSERTS into members (new members)
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS tr_insert_members AFTER INSERT ON members
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO members_changes(Id,Name,LVL,Notes)
    SELECT Id,Name,LVL,Notes || " :Inserted"
    FROM members
    WHERE Name = NEW.Name;
END;
-- this shows all defined triggers
select * from sqlite_master where type = 'trigger';

-- QUERIES to be run from the script after tmp is updated (b,c,d)
-- ADD NEW MEMBERS
-- it should mostly fail (changes are slow and few)
-- this is logged via tr_insert_members
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO members(Name,LVL,Notes) SELECT Name, LVL, Notes FROM tmp;
-- DELETE OLD MEMBERS 
-- logged via tr_delete_members
DELETE FROM members WHERE Name NOT IN (SELECT Name FROM tmp);
-- EMPTY tmp at the end of the script run
DELETE FROM tmp;
```

#### When application runs the only queries that need to be called are:

a) the one which populates `tmp` (from dataframe gathered by rvest)
b) query to add new members from `tmp`
c) query to delete members not in `tmp`
d) query to empty `tmp`

This is thanks to database setup kindly suggested by @forpas. I had never used triggers and finally made some sense of them. Very helpful for logging changes.

Comment: You might consider just adding all the rows into the same table with a timestamp and then fetching the most recent row when you want information about a particular member.  However, your question as written is quite broad, because you ask how to do something and how to do it better and how to design the system better.

Comment: I am sorry, you are right the question is quite broad. Nevertheless the principles would be good information for me as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A proper design for `members_changes` is this:

```
CREATE TABLE members_changes (
  timestamp TEXT DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  Id INTEGER REFERENCES members(Id),
  Name TEXT NOT NULL,
  LVL INTEGER NOT NULL,
  Notes TEXT
);
```

The column `timestamp`'s default value is the current timestamp.

You need an `AFTER INSERT` trigger for the table `tmp`, so that for every inserted row in `tmp`, the respective row from members will be inserted in `members_changes` (if any value of `LVL` or `Notes` is different) and after that the new row from `tmp` will update the row of `members`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS tr_insert_tmp AFTER INSERT ON tmp
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO members_changes(Id,Name,LVL,Notes)
  SELECT Id,Name,LVL,Notes
  FROM members
  WHERE Name = NEW.NAME AND (LVL IS NOT NEW.LVL OR Notes IS NOT NEW.Notes);
  
  UPDATE members 
  SET LVL = NEW.LVL, Notes = NEW.Notes
  WHERE Name = NEW.Name AND (LVL IS NOT NEW.LVL OR Notes IS NOT NEW.Notes);
END;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=7a75a050f6e31be79bc28276b3f93916).

Comment: This is absolutely great. I am trying to replicate with DBeaver, so far I have not dealt with triggers, it just takes a little time to understand.

Comment: Thanks @forpas - I looked into triggers and documented a solution (a little bit expanding on yours) that works for me - and added this expanded solution to my question. Your answer was very helpful - I learned about triggers. Also the dbfiddle demo was great.